# Python - _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!notebook.!frame2.!progressbar"

Tags: python, tkinter

Still doing my schoolwork, i want to add some button and progressbar and i got this problem

This is the code:

```
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(tab2, orient='horizontal', length=286, mode='determinate')

def run_progressbar():
    progress_bar['maximum'] = 100
    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        progress_bar['value'] = i     
        progress_bar.update()           
    progress_bar['value'] = 0          

def start_progressbar():
    progress_bar.start()

def stop_progressbar():
    progress_bar.stop()

def progressbar_stop_after(wait_ms=1000):
    win.after(wait_ms, progress_bar.stop)

ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text='Run Progressbar', command=run_progressbar).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text='Start Progressbar', command=start_progressbar).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text='Stop Immediately', command=stop_progressbar).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text='Stop after second', command=progressbar_stop_after).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='W')
```

Here is the error in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in 
__call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Kuliah\Semester 2\Information Technology\Python\week4\Look and Feel 
Customization\8 GUI_progressbar.py", line 246, in run_progressbar
    progress_bar['value'] = i      #increment progressbar
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1657, in 
__setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in 
configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in 
_configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!notebook.!frame2.!progressbar"
```

Anyone got idea?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: My guess is that you destroy the progress bar then you try to increment it and that causes the error

Comment: @TheLizzard and how to solve it?

Comment: We have to see more of your code for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

running = True

def _run_progressbar():
    try:
        # Incremental the progress bar
        progress_bar["value"] += 1
        # Check if we reached maximum or we should stop running
        if (progress_bar["value"] == 100) or (not running):
            # Reset the value
            progress_bar["value"] = 0
        else:
            # Schedule another increment in 50 ms
            progress_bar.after(50, _run_progressbar)
    except:
        pass

def run_progressbar():
    global running
    if running:
        # Don't start if we are already running
        return None
    running = True
    progress_bar["maximum"] = 100
    progress_bar.after(50, _run_progressbar)

def stop_progressbar():
    # Stop the progress bar
    global running
    running = False
    # Reset its value
    try:
        progress_bar["value"] = 0
    except:
        pass

def progressbar_stop_after(wait_ms=1000):
    progress_bar.after(wait_ms, stop_progressbar)


root = tk.Tk()

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=286,
                               mode='determinate')
progress_bar.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Run Progressbar', command=run_progressbar)
btn.pack()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Stop Immediately', command=stop_progressbar)
btn.pack()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Stop after second', command=progressbar_stop_after)
btn.pack()
```

This runs a tkinter loop and stops if `running` changes to `False` or it reaches the maximum. I have no idea what the difference between the `Start Progressbar` and the `Run Progressbar` buttons is so I just removed one of them.

Comment: Thank you, but i got another problem when use it. it said:
`TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!notebook.!frame2 which already has slaves managed by grid` 
how to solve it?

Comment: @dapdapdap You can't use both `<widget>.pack()` and `<another widget>.grid()` when both widgets are in the same frame/window. I changed your `.grid()` to `.pack()` to make it easier for me to work with. If you revert all of those changes it should fix the problem. TL;DR change the `.pack()`s to `.grid(...)`